# Batch error using cecopy

Tags: batch-file

Having an issue copying these files to a specific directory from the command line any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code:

```
:MK2046
cls
echo MK2046 App/Plat copyBot initialized
echo Make sure you have allowed pcConnection on unit
echo Connect RS 485 cable, press enter once Sync is complete
    :: wait until unit is synced properly
pause
cls
cecopy /is C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\*.reg dev:\Application
cecopy /is C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\*.key dev:\Application
cecopy /is C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\radio.def dev:\Application
cecopy /is C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\Plat\*.reg dev:\Platform
cecopy /is C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\Plat\*.cpy dev:\Platform
pause
goto main
```

here is the error text:

```
Parameter processing error - Too many parameters:  dev:\Platform

Usage:  CeCopy  [options] <Source_FileSpec>  <Destination>

Options:

    /is                  Include same files
    /s                   Include subdirectories

Arguments:

    Source_FileSpec      File specification denoting the source of the copy.
    Destination          Where files should be copied to.

For the source, wild cards or directory names may be specifed, as may be single
files.  The destination can be either a directory or a file name, depending
on the type of source specified.

By default, an argument is assumed to live on a local filesystem.  To indicate
that either argument denotes a location on a device connected via ActiveSync,
prepend 'dev:' to that argument.   To articulate that a local filesystem is
referenced, prepend 'desk:' to the argument.
Exiting.
```

Comment: I'd start by removing the quotes in the middle of the cecopy line and just putting one at the start and end like the examples show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your quoting is messed up. You probably want something like this:

```
cecopy /is "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\App\*.reg" dev:\Application
```

Comment: I changed it to this and it returns this error: `Not enough arguments`

Comment: I've found if I use `dev:"\My computer\Application\"` it gives me the error copy failed `Error:  source pattern does not match a file:  C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx"De
Test\Plat\*.cpy dev:\My

Copy Failed`

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but make sure you don't have any `"` marks in the middle of your path. In your comment above, you have one between `xxxxxxxx` and `De Test`.

Comment: you were correct i had some quotes hanging out, now it's saying copy failed but gives no error, could it be a permissions thing?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the text in the error description, the format for the PC side uses the word "desk" in place of the drive letter (C:):

```
cecopy /is "desk:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\App\*.reg" dev:\Application
```